# Convert Arrays to Object in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

I am creating a Line Chart with d3 in Angular 8.
I following some example with `TEMPERATURES`. But my API is getting following format.

**Data from API**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "dashboard_data": [
            [
                2014-04-01,
                2920.0,
                239.44000000000003
            ],
            [
                2014-04-02,
                2260.0,
                185.32000000000002
            ],
            [
                2014-04-03,
                156.0,
                12.792
            ],
            [
                2014-04-04,
                980.0,
                80.36
            ],
            [
                2014-04-05,
                1515.0,
                124.22999999999999
            ],
        ],


    }
}
```

**Need data in this format**

```
TEMPERATURES = [
    {
        'values': [
            {'date': new Date('2012-09-05'), 'temperature': 77.7},
            {'date': new Date('2012-09-06'), 'temperature': 74.2},
            {'date': new Date('2012-09-07'), 'temperature': 76.0},
        ]
    },
    ];
```

I am looking for solution, how I convert `dashboard_data` with `values`?
TIA

Comment: Where is 'New York' in your input?

Comment: @AdritaSharma, that nothing, just remove it.

Comment: 2920.0,  239.44000000000003 - Which of these 2 is temperature?

Comment: i would say ask backend api to change there response data if possible, Because re processing data on UI reduce the application performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 TEMPERATURES = [];

  constructor() {
    let obj = {};
    obj["values"] = this.input.data.dashboard_data.map(item => ({
      date: new Date(item[0]),
      temperature : item[2]
    }))
    this.TEMPERATURES.push(obj)
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghtxre?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: how can I add extra key with values? like if like to add ` "id":"1", "values":[....]`

Comment: @user12552117 `obj["id"] = "1"`.

Comment: @user12552117 try `obj["id"] = "New York"

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how to convert temperature. However, you can try the following approach:

```
let temperatures = [];
const result = obj.data.dashboard_data
    .map(([d, h, t]) => ({date: new Date(d), temperature: t}));
temperatures.push({values: result});
```

An example:

```js
let obj = {
    "status": 200,
    "data":
    {
         "dashboard_data": [
             [
                2014 - 04 - 01,
                2920.0,
                239.44000000000003
             ],
             [
                2014 - 04 - 02,
                2260.0,
                185.32000000000002
             ],
             [
                2014 - 04 - 03,
                156.0,
                12.792
             ],
             [
                2014 - 04 - 04,
                980.0,
                80.36
             ],
             [
                2014 - 04 - 05,
                1515.0,
                124.22999999999999
             ],
         ]
     }
 };
     
 let temperatures = [];
 const result = obj.data.dashboard_data
     .map(([d, h, t]) => ({date: new Date(d), temperature: t}));
 temperatures.push({values: result});
 console.log(temperatures);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over each item in `dashboard_data` array and then pick `date` and `temperature` from it and push it to `TEMPERATURE` array:

```
dashboard_data.forEach((item)=>{
  TEMPERATURES.push({'date': new Date(item[0]), 'temperature': item[2]});
 }
)
```

```js
let dashboard_data =  [
            [
                '2014-04-01',
                2920.0,
                239.44000000000003
            ],
            [
                '2014-04-02',
                2260.0,
                185.32000000000002
            ],
            [
                '2014-04-03',
                156.0,
                12.792
            ],
            [
                '2014-04-04',
                980.0,
                80.36
            ],
            [
                '2014-04-05',
                1515.0,
                124.22999999999999
            ],
        ]
        
let TEMPERATURES = [];

dashboard_data.forEach((item)=>{
    TEMPERATURES.push({'date': new Date(item[0]), 'temperature': item[2]});
 }
)

console.log(TEMPERATURES);
```